# Continue Actions in Background state

Tags: iphone, ios, download, background

I have a problem with working in background mode ... I have an application for iPhone and it download some information from internet (for example RSS Feed) when my application enter to the background it stops download. When I call from background function that open connection and begin to download it stops, like something happens with my internet connection like it closed. Con somebody answer me can I continue downloading or starts a new one in background mode or I can't. I read [This](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) but I can't understand if I can do work except

```
* audio - The application plays audible content to the user while in the background.
* location - The application keeps users informed of their location, even while running in the background.
* voip - The application provides the ability for the user to make phone calls using an Internet connection.
```

in background mode.

Thank you for answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all, that Apple document you mentioned has exactly what you need.
- Second, read this post, [Download data in background with iOS4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704037/download-data-in-background-with-ios4/)
- Third, to make things clear, what you need is not audio/location/voip, what you need is the **Completing a Finite Length Task in the Background** section, which was discussed and was presented with a short code sample in that Apple document.