# iOS Application idles and then locks

Tags: ios

What delegate is called in this situation if I have an app running.

Over time, if iPad is set to lock after 2 mins, what is its state? Does the app still run? or does it suspend?

I'd like to know thanks

Answer (score 3):

If the iOS device automatically locks after a period of inactivity, the same thing happens as when it's locked by pressing the lock button: the app briefly goes into the background before being suspended. (Unless of course it is an audio-playing app or other app that requests extra execution time, in which case it may stay in the background longer, or indefinitely, without being suspended).

In terms of `UIApplicationDelegate` methods, `applicationWillResignActive:` will be called first, followed by `applicationDidEnterBackground:`.

Comment: alright cool, if I have stuff downloading, is there a way to prevent it from being inactive?

Comment: Yeah, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704037/download-data-in-background-with-ios4