# iPhone sdk, Running app in background and send frequent http request

Tags: iphone, http, multitasking

I am trying to take advantage of iPhone 4 multitasking feature. I want to run app in background and frequently send http request to send/receive data, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to request running time while your app is backgrounded.

See [Multitasking Developer's Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Although, depending on the intent of your http requests, push notifications may be a viable alternative.

This may be necessary because you aren't providing audio, voip, or location services, so your app can't run in the background indefinitely.

Comment: I agree. Specifically, pay attention to the **Listing 4-2  Starting a background task at quit tim** in the PDF.

Comment: @diwup has a workaround in his previous post to get more running time while in the background (although it's not guaranteed you will always get it)

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, there is actually very little time-slicing going on in the "multi-tasking" iOS 4.x.   What goes on instead is really just application suspend / resume.  When an application is sent to the background upon the user tapping the home button, it will stop getting execute cycles after a short while (*).

(*) There are a few exceptions.   Applications which declare themselves as "VoIP providers", location-based apps, and music apps can get background execute cycles, presumably only though to perform those very specific operations in response to corresponding events (like a "significant change in location" occurring).    Some apps apparently try to stretch the rules and find undocumented or not-strongly-documented techniques to continue getting background execute cycles.

And the "requested running time" that Undeadlegion mentioned is limited in duration.

The reality is that on iOS4, applications are not allowed to run continuously in the background.

Comment: "And the "requested running time" that Undeadlegion mentioned is limited in duration." Yes, it's limited. But you can request a new permit every time the old one is about to run out of time (and then ends the old one). Besides, the time limit is 10 minutes based on observation. Already long enough for many http tasks isn't it?

Comment: You're still not addressing the fact that background execution is limited.   Yes you can apply for a new permit, but that doesn't mean you're going to get one.    It's better not to mislead people into thinking that "background" processing in iOS like like general purpose OS where processes run time-sliced against each other without limitations.

Answer (score 1):

@Undeadlegion has suggested a plausible way to achieve your goal. To be more clear, take a look at my previous answer to a similar question at SO, [iphone - Connecting to server in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594348/iphone-connecting-to-server-in-background/)

Comment: The OP mentioned that he wants to "run app in background and frequently send http requests...".  Directing him at a solution where the app can apply for a *finite* length extension of run time does not directly meet his goals.    It is more correct to set expectations that there is no such thing as continuous, unlimited background operation on iOS 4 "multi-tasking."

Comment: @Bogatyr see my comment at your answer.