# iOS background application network access

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, location

I have an application that requires location tracking and I think it fits squarely within one of the allowable background models.  However, I need to post to a network service when there are significant changes of location.  I've seen write-ups that state network access is prohibited in background processing, but I didn't read that in Apple's docs.

Does anyone know if it's kosher (wrt Apple policies) to make occasional and very quick network updates in a background process?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Good point, according to the Apple documentation only the following usages are allowed in background and each service should be registered:

> - audio—The app plays audible content to the user while in the background. (This content includes streaming audio or video content
>     using AirPlay.)
> - location—The app keeps users informed of their location, even while it is running in the background.
> - voip—The app provides the ability for the user to make phone calls using an Internet connection.
> - newsstand-content—The app is a Newsstand app that downloads and processes magazine or newspaper content in the background.
> - external-accessory—The app works with a hardware accessory that needs to deliver updates on a regular schedule through the External
>     Accessory framework.
> - bluetooth-central—The app works with a Bluetooth accessory that needs to deliver updates on a regular schedule through the
>     CoreBluetooth framework.

Other than this services, you can create a *Finite-Length Task in the Background* that actually give you the possibility to end a network process.

> This can be important if your app is performing some important task,
>   such as writing user data to disk or downloading an important file
>   from a network server.

Regarding your question, it's not really clear if you can or not can do a quick network connection if you've a location service running in background. I would say YES for a short connection, but not totally sure. Since iOS 4.0 this usage was denied and clear in documentation, now that part has been removed.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** if you use background for just quick connection. Apple won't allow you to run in the background as you want.

**NO** If your app does not fall in the Voip, music or GPS category; then you can't run in background.

more here: [Update my app when it is in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310319/update-my-app-when-it-is-in-background)

---

You could use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).

`ASIHTTPRequest` has a property `setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:`. default is `NO`, you may turn on `YES` so you have background network process.

Comment: Thx.  To clarify, the question is really whether Apple allows network access when running in background.

Comment: Thx again, but the link doesn't really answer my question - that's more about finishing an existing network request.  I want to run indefinitely in the background and do the occasional network request (let's say send 1000 bytes hourly).  It's a question of Apple policy around *network* access in background apps.

Comment: well then, answer would be NO. apple won't allow you to do that (if possible).

Comment: Can you point me to anything written from Apple or someone who has had an app rejected for this?  This is hugely important to me, so I need to know for certain whether yes or no.

Comment: it's possible to do. try to look other implementation like `ASIHTTPRequest`.

Answer (score 1):

Apple documentation seems a bit unclear on the strict policy. There are definitely applications in the app store that make sporadic network calls while running in the background as a location-based application. An example is the Geoloqi application.