# Can iPhone app which runs in background send data over network to a remote server?

Tags: objective-c, ios, background, gps

This application is location awareness app. It uses GPS details so it can be run in background. But is it possible to send the collected data to a remote server while the app is in background? or maybe when the screen is locked?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS background application network access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613357/ios-background-application-network-access)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Required background modes` add `App registers for location updates` in plist, this will make application work in background and you can send location updates to server.
Here consider that your location services are not continuously on, else it will drain complete battery of device.
Hope this help you..