# Firebase continue to listen for events in background

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I've developed a communication application and I'm beginning to notice that my app doesn't receive Firebase event calls when the app is in the background.  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613357/ios-background-application-network-access) question that touches on network operations in the background, but I sort of assumed the Firebase library handled these things.

How can I do things like updating the badge on new messages when it my firebase events aren't fired unless the app is open?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what my problem was.  I am using a singleton for my message data receiver, and by calling its `setup` function (which calls the `.observe` methods for various Firebase locations) in my `AppDelegate` instead of in the the `viewDidLoad` method for my message view controller, I got it working <s>perfectly!</s> pretty inconsistently.

Sometimes it updates it immediately, while other times it updates with a delay, still other times the app badge doesn't update at all until I force close and restart it.  If someone knows a more reliable solution I would love to hear it.