# Can an not native Apple watch app work when the iPhone is locked?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-watch, watchos

I am working for Apple Watch (OS-1) and consuming the web services from iPhone application.

I'm finding difficulty to access iPhone application when iPhone device gets locked. Is there a way to access it while locked?

Comment: I suggest to use WatchOS2 instead WatchOS1 and look at this video from Apple and I'm sure this can help you https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=713. If you want use Watch OS 1 I think you can see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864553/ios-http-request-while-in-background

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course work.

Using this you can make call to Phone app

```
[WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:callDict reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {


    }];
```

And In the appDelegate you can handle your stuff.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void(^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply {
  }
```

And One another thing for make call in watch app there is [MMWormhole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole) for Instant call.

Comment: yes it's true, im doing the same. when device is locked i am not able to communicate the iPhone application it self.