# Alamofire in Background Mode

Tags: ios, swift, background, alamofire

I need to make a request with Alamofire and if it fails because of no internet connection, I must switch the app to background mode and keep trying to make the request in background.
When the request is successfully completed, I show a local notification.
I've already searched about background mode, but I didn't figure it out how to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: you could chechk this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864553/ios-http-request-while-in-background

Comment: Thank you @BurakÖztürk, I didn't get it yet, but I'll let you know when I find a solution